# Unable to access __collect() with minimal AssemblyScript runtime

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

In my AssemblyScript project, I have the following configuration:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "debug": {
      "outFile": "build/debug.wasm",
      "textFile": "build/debug.wat",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "debug": true
    },
    "release": {
      "outFile": "build/release.wasm",
      "textFile": "build/release.wat",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "optimizeLevel": 3,
      "shrinkLevel": 0,
      "converge": false,
      "noAssert": false
    }
  },
  "options": {
    "bindings": "esm"
  }
}
```

Based on the [interface documentation](https://www.assemblyscript.org/runtime.html#interface), I expected the `exportRuntime` flag to result in a `__collect` function being included in the exports of the generated bindings:

```js
import { myFunction, __collect } from 'my-package';

myFunction();
__collect(); // undefined!
```

However, I don't see any such function in the bindings, and no errors appear during a build. There is no `__collect` export. Have I misunderstood how the minimal runtime works, or configured this incorrectly?

---

*Hopefully I've included all necessary context here, but the rest of the project's code can be found at https://github.com/donmccurdy/keyframe-resample/blob/main/asconfig.json*.